# By clicking on any of the list item,a new layout should open in android using fragments

Tags: android

I am developing an android application using fragments.Main layout should be divided into two fragments,one is listview fragment and other should be layout which will have edit box and other items.Images I am able to display in 2nd layout but unable to start a layout which I supposed to do.If you have any idea about this please share that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fragment demo in APIDemo, Plz, take alook at this. I remember it have a example like yours..

Answer (score 0):

Use fragment transaction to set fragment.

```
Fragment f=SomeFragment.newInstance(someparams...)
FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.someid, f); 
ft.commit();
```

R.id.someid is id of your fragment in layout.